# Error accessing personal sites via TokenHelper

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to run the OfficeDevPnP code sample for One Drive provisioning for branding available [here](http://dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices-detail/1948).

The code that I use to access personal site using `TokenHelper.cs` is shown below:

```
 Uri siteUri = new Uri(personalSiteUrl);
 string realm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(siteUri); 
 string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, siteUri.Authority, realm).AccessToken;
```

However it is giving following error:

```
 The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. - {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90002: No service namespace named '011105d4-7ab7-4e93-9c79-27b6ac63d593' was found in the data store.\r\nTrace ID: a37994c6-3ab0-4fc5-8ae6-14a4bf6fa753\r\nCorrelation ID: b684b897-007d-4099-bd5f-976941b6d4d2\r\nTimestamp: 2015-10-29 05:54:12Z","error_codes":[90002],"timestamp":"2015-10-29 05:54:12Z","trace_id":"a37994c6-3ab0-4fc5-8ae6-14a4bf6fa753","correlation_id":"b684b897-007d-4099-bd5f-976941b6d4d2"}
```

I tried to search for the correlation ID in ULS logs, but could not find them.

Please help on how to solve or approach this issue.